# Servlet not displaying anything neither showing any error

Tags: java, servlets

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/Site.css"/>



<body style="height: 800px">
     <pre>
   <!-- <h1 class="black"><center>Registration Detail<img src="res/login.png"/></center></h1>-->

    <h3>Cast Your Vote To The Right Persion</h3>    

    <form width="200" action ="regservlet" method="POST">

        <legend><i>Fill Up Your Details</i></legend>
        Voter Name     :<input placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" name="vname">

        Voter ID       :<input placeholder="Enter VoterID" type="text" name="vid">

        Email          :<input placeholder="Enter Email" type="text" name="vemail">

        Age            :<input placeholder="Enter Age(>18)" type="text" name="vage">

        Address        :<input placeholder="Enter Address" type ="text" name="vaddress">

        Pin Code       :<input placeholder="Enter PIN" type ="text" name="vpin">

        State          :<input placeholder="Enter State"type ="text" name="vstate">



    <input type="Submit" class="button Green" value="Submit"/>  <input type="Reset" class ="button red" value="Reset"/>
    </form>  
    <h4>Already Registered <a href="Login.html">Login Here</a></h4>
   <%-- ${requestScope.msg1}
    ${requestScope.msg2}
    ${requestScope.msg3}--%>
    </pre>


</body>
```

servlet

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package web1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jdbc.DAOLayer;

/**
 *
 * @author 1405075
 */
public class regservlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

            String name=request.getParameter("vname");
        String id=request.getParameter("vid");
        String mail=request.getParameter("vemail");
        String age=request.getParameter("vage");
        String add=request.getParameter("vaddress");
        String pin=request.getParameter("vpin");
        String state=request.getParameter("vstate");
        String q = "select * from voter where vid ='"+id+"';";
        ResultSet rs = DAOLayer.selectData(q);

        try{
        if(rs.next())
        { RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Registration.jsp");
        rd.include(request,response);
        out.println("<font color='Red'><h3>Please enter valid voter ID</h3></font><br>");
        out.println("<font color='Red'><h3>This Voter ID is already registered with us.</h3></font>");
        }


        else  

         //if(p.equals(cp))
            {
               String query = "insert into voter(vname,vid,vage,vaddress,vpin,vstate,vemail) values('"+name+"','"+id+"','"+age+"','"+add+"','"+pin+"','"+state+"','"+mail+");";
                int ur = DAOLayer.updateData(query);
                if(ur>0){
                 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Registration.jsp");
                  rd.include(request,response);
                  out.print("<h3><font color= 'Green'>Registered Successfully</font></h3>");
                }


            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.print(e);
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    
        Loginservlet
        web1.Loginservlet
    
    
        Registrationservlet
        web1.Registrationservlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>regservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web1.regservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registrationservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Loginservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>regservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/regservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

[image]

On running my servlet it doesnt display anything neither showing any error.

Comment: Edit your question and explain your problem with more detail like what exactly you want to do and what is happening. Code alone will not help us to help you.

Comment: by taking all the details from user i am calling the servlet,now through servlet i want to store that details in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You are passing queries as parameters to DAOLayer. When you are passing query as String the corresponding values of variables are not sent. It is just a String = "select * from voter where vid ='"+id+"'"; .The value of varible id is not sent here. Instead of it define queries within methods in DAOLayer and receive values of variables there. The correct MVC approach to do this is using Beans. Create a simple Registration Bean like this :-

```
public class RegistrationBean {
   private String name;
   private String id;
   private String age;
   private String address;
   private String pin;
   private String state;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Modify your servlet code to set the bean properties like this :-

```
RegistrationBean rb=new RegistrationBean();
        rb.setName(name);
        rb.setId(id);
        rb.setAge(age);
        rb.setAddress(add);
        rb.setPin(pin);
        rb.setState(state);
```

For checking the existing user, modify your selectData method in DAOLayer to receive just id and call it like this :-

```
ResultSet rs = DAOLayer.selectData(id);
```

Use `rd.forward(request,response);` instead of `rd.include(request,response);` . After execution of this statement control will be transferred to Registration.jsp and these statements :-

```
out.println("<font color='Red'><h3>Please enter valid voter ID</h3></font><br>");
        out.println("<font color='Red'><h3>This Voter ID is already registered with us.</h3></font>");
```

will not be executed. This is another error in your code. For insert operation modify your updateData method to receive RegistrationBean. Receive value of variables there using getter methods of bean that is like this :-

```
    public int updateData(RegistrationBean rb){
    String name=rb.getName();
    String id=rb.getId();
    String age=rb.getAge();
    String address=rb.getAddress();
    String pin=rb.getPin();
    String state=rb.getState();
       .
       . 
 rest of your code. Execute insert query here.

    }
```

Here transferring the control to Registration.jsp is meaning less. Create a HTML page named Success.html which shows success message for transaction. Create another page named Failure.Html which shows failure message and call it like this :-

```
if(ur>0){
              response.sendRedirect("success.html");
           }else{
              response.sendRedirect("failure.html");
           }
```

Hope it will help. Mark the problem solved by clicking right mark on top left side of my answer if it does. If not, let me know. Happy Coding :)